# Can I programmatically access Vagrant's auto-corrected port forwarding?

Tags: port, vagrant, vagrantfile

I hard-coded a port forwarding in my Vagrantfile and now it collides with another box running on my machine.

I am aware Vagrant can [detect port collisions and correct them](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html). But one of the recipes I'm running depends on knowing the port for some other configuration.

Can I programmatically find out which port Vagrant detected as not in use so the recipe can make use of it?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in command for this, but if you're using VirtualBox as your provider you can get port information using:

```
$ VBoxManage showvminfo $(cat .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id) --details --machinereadable | egrep Forwarding
```

Giving you an output similar to:

```
Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2222,,22"
Forwarding(1)="tcp8080,tcp,,8080,,80"
```

In the above, port 22 of the VM is forwarded to 2222 of the host, and 80 to 8080.

The `VMNAME` can be found by using vagrant's `global-status` command:

```
$ vagrant global-status
id       name    provider   state   directory
------------------------------------------------------------------------
78cf051  default virtualbox running /path/to/Vagrantfile
```

In the example above, `default` is the `VMNAME`.

Comment: That might work on the host, but I'd like to find out on the guest. As I said, I'd like to use the information in a recipe...

Comment: You can combine this answer with Virtualbox's guest properties (guest metadata) to pass info into the guest machine. Inside guest machine you can fetch this data with `VBoxControl guestproperty` (which will be installed if you have Guest Additions. Obviously you can make it easier and just write the port into some temp file which will be shared between host & guest.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [vagrant-portinfo](https://github.com/kuboj/vagrant-portinfo) plugin:

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-portinfo`
$ vagrant portinfo
server1 (84a1587) running
------------------------------------------------
guest: 22       host: 2201
guest: 8080     host: 8083
```

You'll have to do a bit of grepping to parse the output. Adding programmatic querying of forwarded ports has been on the roadmap in Vagrant for years now, and there's still an [open issue discussing it](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1415).

Comment: Good to know but again, this is a solution to find the information on the host. I need it in the guest OS.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention the guest OS requirement. Also, depending on your config manager, you can delegate the port forward query to the management host and then use the port info in recipes.

Comment: True, I can delegate the query. Sorry for not being clear on the guest OS requirement in my question.

Comment: Appears to be Virtualbox only at time of writing, I'm interested in a docker compatible solution.